# UIButton's background color progressively getting darker on touch down drag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I've been encountering this bug where the UIButton progressively gets darker when the UIButton is being dragged down (See animated gif below for demonstration). The UIButton was created using the interface builder and only the background color was changed.

What is the issue causing this behavior?

EDIT:

Button is initialized with this method (Title color was changed too).

```
- (void)initUserButton{
    [self.userButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:ATTENDANCE_HEADER_ACCENT]];
    [self.userButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

[image: Select Institution button does not revert to its original color]

Comment: post the code to change button color

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I've edited my post to include the code.

Comment: Have you used any tint color. Try, clearing it as well

Comment: @julesian : Are you setting button color for other states as well like selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the **embedded frameworks** all along. There was a category overriding the `setHighlighted` method for UIButton and it is affecting the whole project with it.

I have fixed the bug in the category and made it to only override on custom buttons that the framework will use.

Answer (score 0):

**either you have to change background color of that button from storyboard**

**or use this code**

```
-(void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
if(highlighted) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.643 blue:0.282 alpha:1];
} else {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
}
[super setHighlighted:highlighted];
}
```

Comment: I have made the background color to default (clearColor), however the behavior is still the same.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.